# How to access the parent page elements of an Iframe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How to access the parent page elements of an Iframe. 
e.g. If i have a page index.htm and another page in an IFrame in index.htm and want to access the elements of index.htm from that IFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript:

```
parent.document.getElementById('myElement');
```

jquery:

```
$('#myElement', window.parent.document);
```

Answer (score 0):

See my reply to a similar question here:
[move input text from iframe to main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304076/move-input-text-from-iframe-to-main-window/2304138#2304138)

basically, parent gives you the "window" object of the parent window.  You can then access window.document to get document... and therefore, you can get window.document.getElementById() by using parent.document.getElementById(id);